# Use of undefined constant erorr in php

Tags: php, constants, undefined

I receive errors(mentioned below code) when I switched my code to another system,

Configurations:

OS : Windows 7
php server : Xampp

Please help me to resolve this problem. thanks in advance.

CODE:

```
<?php
class settings{
    public $theme;
    public $db_pf;

    function __construct(){
        $this->theme="default";
        $this->db_pf="task_";
        $this->paths();
        $this->abbr();
        $this->errors();

        $this->enable_db_config();
    }
    function paths(){
        define(ROOT,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
        define(BP,"/task/");
        define(ABSPATH,"/task/ta-admin/");
        define(ADMPATH,"/task/administrator/");
        define(INCLUDE_PATH,ABSPATH."includes/");
        define(MODULE_PATH,ABSPATH."modules/");
        define(CONTENT_PATH,ABSPATH."contents/");
        define(THEME_PATH,ABSPATH."templates/".$this->theme."/");
        define(STYLE_PATH,THEME_PATH."styles/");
        define(IMAGE_PATH,THEME_PATH."images/");
        define(JS_PATH,BP."assets/js/");
        define(JQ_PATH,BP."assets/jq/");
    }
    function enable_db_config(){
        include(ROOT.BP."ta-includes/class-db-config.php");
    }
    function abbr(){
        define(task_title,"Admin-Quit Tasker-");
        define(LOGIN_TITLE," Administrator Login...");
        define(SLOGAN,"Enabling Solutions to your Tasks...");
    }
    function errors(){
        define(NOTFOUND,"Page not found");
        define(GOBACK," please press ok to go back...");    
    }
}
$obj_settings=new settings();
?>
```

**ERRORS:**

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant ROOT - assumed 'ROOT' in C:\xampp\htdocs\task\ta-includes\class-settings.php on line 14

Notice: Use of undefined constant BP - assumed 'BP' in C:\xampp\htdocs\task\ta-includes\class-settings.php on line 15

Notice: Use of undefined constant ABSPATH - assumed 'ABSPATH' in C:\xampp\htdocs\task\ta-includes\class-settings.php on line 16

Notice: Use of undefined constant INCLUDE_PATH - assumed 'INCLUDE_PATH' in C:\xampp\htdocs\task\ta-includes\class-settings.php on line 17

Notice: Use of undefined constant CONTENT_PATH - assumed 'CONTENT_PATH' in C:\xampp\htdocs\task\ta-includes\class-settings.php on line 18

Notice: Use of undefined constant THEME_PATH - assumed 'THEME_PATH' in C:\xampp\htdocs\task\ta-includes\class-settings.php on line 19

Notice: Use of undefined constant STYLE_PATH - assumed 'STYLE_PATH' in C:\xampp\htdocs\task\ta-includes\class-settings.php on line 20

Notice: Use of undefined constant JS_PATH - assumed 'JS_PATH' in C:\xampp\htdocs\task\ta-includes\class-settings.php on line 21

Notice: Use of undefined constant JQ_PATH - assumed 'JQ_PATH' in C:\xampp\htdocs\task\ta-includes\class-settings.php on line 22
```

Comment: Which part of the error messages do you not understand in specific?

Answer (score 7):

Your constants need to be strings. So you have to "wrap" them in quotes like this:

```
define('ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
       ^    ^
```

When in doubt, always check the [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php), in that case [define()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

**Add:**
Also defining constants in a function is, what I find, a bit "**dodgy**". If you insist on not moving them to another (e.g. `config`) file which is loaded in the very beginning then at least take them out of the class construct.

Comment: Thank you, that works fine. But in my another system I never used quotes before yet they worked well, can you tell me should I change config in php.ini file

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell you why, as I have no idea what your "other system" is. Just look at the examples for [`define()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) and see how it is supposed to be done.

Comment: @Kmanikandan: If you fix something, fix it at the right place. This time it's your code, not a PHP ini setting. As those two systems differ, you need to learn the lesson that ini settings vary and you should make the most out of that: Enable error reporting / logging on **your development system** to the highest level to improve your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mis-understood what Define & constants are/do it doesn't really make sense to  define a constant in that way from within an Object.

Perhaps this is a better approach to what you are doing:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Alternatively, the most common usage of setting up items using defines is withing a si9mple setting or config file...